# I can not access phpMyAdmin on XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have my XAMMP installed on WINDOWS 8. I can access my localhost like this`localhost:800` I am trying to access phpmyadmin from XAMPP but when I am clicking on the button or type in  `http://localhost:800/phpmyadmin/`  I am just getting a white homepage without anything on it?! Does anyone know whats gonig on? It worked fine yesterday.

Comment: Dit it work before you changed the port from 80 to 800?

Comment: @com2ghz: Yes that was before 2 months because there was conflict with tomcat 8  and it worked then fine  until yesterday

Comment: 1. Did you start MySql in XAMPP control panel? 2. browse to: `\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` and check if `phpMyAdmin` alias  is aloud

Comment: Ham it works now I just refreshed the browser serveral times although I tried the same 3 hours ago but nothing happened on phpmyadmin homepage but it reacted now also it works.

Comment: @Captain: Yes I have restarted it several time before. i have the following in the httpd-xampp.conf file `    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>`

Comment: teamviewer also uses port 80, uninstalling teamviewer solved my problem

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue with uppercase letters

> http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/

Using lowercase letters solved the issue for me.

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Running XAMPP v3.2.2 on windows 10

Answer (score 7):

Open `phpMyAdmin>config.inc.php` in your favourite text editor.

Search for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

Replace it with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

browse localhost/phpmyadmin.
and username will be root, no password

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me? Could you explain the issue a bit more? What's happening here?

Comment: That worked and I am ever so grateful starting where it states"Open phpMyAdmin>config.inc.php in your favourite text editor."

Answer (score 4):

when I was a novice in this path, I had faced that kind of problem and then I solved it by myself.

That is very simple. Don't get panic. I think you won't need to do any code works or any search.

Just, in your address `http://localhost:800/phpmyadmin/`

just delete `:800` things.

then your address will be `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

hit enter and watch your path is working...:)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is common and can easily be resolved! So no need to worry.

- First of all, open XAMPP in your device and install the MySQL and Apache by clicking on the service checkbox beside them having a red cross on it (which will change to a green tick once the modules are installed).
- After that, click on the start button to start the modules (as shown in the image).
  [image]

- Once you have completed the above procedure, open your browser and type **https://localhost/phpmyadmin/**.
- You can now use your phpmyadmin to create a database.

But in some cases, it might show a warning of **Your connection is not private**.

In such cases, all you need to do is to click on the Advanced option shown below and click on the link **Proceed to page (unsafe)** link.

You are now ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **start MySQL** on the XAMPP control panel to allow the Apache server to access the database in order to authenticate to the administration panel (phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score -2):

try to know the server's ip address by typing ipconfig in cmd, example: 192.168.22.5/phpmyadmin