# Xampp- cannot access phpmyadmin from browser, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using windows machine and trying to access "localhost/phpmyadmin" from XAMPP but cannot access the page from browser. The browsers show ["The connection was reset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKJBu.png). I have tried running simple PHP script from the htdocs folder and it works fine. But still I cannot access the admin panel for MySql. localhost/dashboard is accessible but the page doesn't load properly, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOCSM.png). I have tried accessing using IP and port i.e. 127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin but still no luck. Also please check the screenshot of my [XAMPP control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMUSA.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can not access phpMyAdmin on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255567/i-can-not-access-phpmyadmin-on-xampp)

Comment: Check the PHP error log: ...\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified" - this prompt shows up when I try to access the log from the control panel. @PhilipPetrov.

Comment: Tried but no luck. @SimoneRossaini

Comment: Create the directory ...\xampp\php\logs\ and put an empty file with name php_error_log (no extension), then restart XAMPP and Apache, try to open phpmyadmin and check the log.

Comment: Created the file at the specified directory and tried opening phpmyadmin. But the php_error_log is empty.