# phpmyadmin doesn't work. it says site inaccessisble

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

xampp works very well, but when i try to access phpmyadmin, it doesn't work,it says "site inaccessible"

I've tried everything, can someone help me fix this issue please.
i've already tried deleting the cache.
I've tried changing the port to 8012 for exeple instead of 80
I've tried allowing the port 80 in the firewall
still the same issue
[image]
[image]

fix the issue and access to phpmyadmin

Comment: What have you seen when you checked the error logs?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255567/i-can-not-access-phpmyadmin-on-xampp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your screen apache is listening on port 59063 but in the other you are connecting to 8080.
Anyway try to connect to the server root and verify you see the xampp dashboard then add /phpmyadmin/

Comment: turns out it's the antivirus that's blocking me from accessing to the site

Comment: @miniar, if your problem is already solved, answer yourself this question, so it won't appear as unsolved.